# Cannot create an initial context from a Swing client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

Please see the code below:

```
try {
            //InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  
             "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);      

            MySessionRemote hb = (MySessionRemote) ctx.lookup("MySessionRemote");
            System.out.println(hb.getResult());
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The error I get from a Swing app is`:(javax.naming.NoInitialContextException) javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]`

I have not worked with Java for a while so this could be quite straightforward.

**Update**

I am using version 4.1 of Glassfish.  I have added references to the following jars inside the NetBeans project:

```
appserv-rt.jar
gf-client.jar
javaee.jar
```

I can now get an InitialContext.  However, I cannot lookup the bean i.e. this line fails:

```
MySessionRemote hb = (MySessionRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb.MySessionRemote");
```

The exception is a `NamingException` i.e. `Lookup Failed`.  I believe the name of the bean may be wrong. Here is the bean:

package ejb;

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Resource(name = "MySessionRemote")
@Remote
public interface MySessionRemote {
    public String getResult();
}
```

What should the name of the bean be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which application server are you using? E.g. when using Glassfish that class can be found in the `glassfish-naming.jar` file. That JAR needs to be on your classpath. I assume other application servers have a similar JAR file.

In fact, when you have that JAR on your classpath you could simply use the no-args constructor of `InitialContext` since the JAR already contains a `jndi.properties` file with the following content:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
# Required to add a javax.naming.spi.StateFactory for CosNaming that
# supports dynamic RMI-IIOP.
java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
```

Comment: Where is this jar file? I  cannot find it in glassfish/lib (which is cumin my classpath).  Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Glassfish are you using?

Comment: I have added an update to the question answering your question.  Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Two things : I am not sure what you need the @Resource annotation in MySessionRemote for. And secondly : Check the log file. It should print out the name on deployment that can be used for the remote lookup.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to find the EJB name in the logs.